Usage of ほう in this sentence
自分の裏側を堂々と吐露する椿の、それは自分の財布を開いて見せるかのような赤裸々さがあった。
その行動を受け取るほうが試されるくらいの正直さだ。
In the first sentence the narrator comments that person telling him that is being very honest, like if he was showing him his wallet.
I'm not sure how to take ほうが here. I understand "その行動を受け取る" to accept those words/actions  試されるくらいの正直さだ a honesty to the level of being put to test, but I can't quite get why is ほうが being used here?

"ほう" in the last sentence is almost the same as "人" in this case. So you can replace ほう with 人 to understand the sentence, but using ほう is more appropriate here.
So, why ほう is used here? What's the difference between ほう and 人?

"ほう" focuses more on a role.
"ほう" refers to one side of a complementary role.
"ほう" can refer not only to humans, but also anything else as long as it has a role.

Here is an example:
A: 今は学校に通ってる。 (I go to school now.)
B: いつ生徒になったの。 (When did you become
a student.)
A: 私は教えるほうだよ。 (I have a role of teaching. = I am a teacher.)
In this exchange, A says he goes to school, which B misinterprets as meaning A is a student. A clarifies that A has a role of teaching, indicating that A is in the complementary role of teacher, not student.
What if A had replies like this instead:
私は教える人だよ。
This would sound a bit odd in this context because it describes A as someone who habitually teaches, rather than emphasizing his role in this specific situation.
Here is another example:
昼に活動するほうを昼行性、夜に活動するほうを夜行性と言う。
Something that is active during the day is called diurnal, and something that is active at night is called nocturnal.
In this example, ほう refers to all the living things in common, so it cannot replace to 人 here.
Now we've clarified ほう, let's return to your question.
The first sentence describe 椿(assuming she is a girl, since 椿 is a common girl's name) as being very honest -- so honest that it's like she is showing even her wallet.
The second sentence starts with "その行動を受け取るほう," meaning "the person who has the role of receiving her actions." Based on the context, there are two roles here:

椿's role of proving her innocence
Another person's role of interpreting her actions - - possibly someone who suspects 椿 of something.

Since the first sentence mention that 椿 is being honest, like showing her wallet, we can imagine a situation like this:
Someone believes his money has been stolen and suspects 椿. However, 椿 is being so open and honest, perhaps even offering to show her wallet to prove her innocence.
Now, let's understand the full meaning of the second sentence:
その行動を受け取るほうが試されるくらいの正直さだ。
This means that 椿 is being so honest, to the point where the person who suspected her feels like he is being tested on whether he can accept her innocence. In other words, while he was supposed to be testing her honesty, he now feels that his own honesty is being tested by how open she has been.
